# How to get User data (Public profile and Email ) In ionic framework

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, oauth, cordova-plugins

I am working on Ionic Mobile Application. After Creating Facebook Login button(Working fine) i want to get User data (Public profile and Email for my database.

My Index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script><script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Controller.js

```
.controller('login',['$scope','myService','$location','$state','$timeout',function($scope,myService,$location,$state,$timeout)
{
  $scope.fbLogin = function ($cordovaOauth,$http) {
facebookLogin(window.cordovaOauth, window.http);
console.log(fbLogin);
}
}])
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','starter.services','ngSanitize',  'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth']);
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong. 
And Sometimes i Get $cordovaOauth error. 
Modular is not Injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function login(){
facebookLogin(window.cordovaOauth, window.http);
}

function facebookLogin($cordovaOauth, $http)
{
$cordovaOauth.facebook("1633195863589792", ["email", "public_profile"], {redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback"}).then(function(result){
    displayData($http, result.access_token);
},  function(error){
        alert("Error: " + error);
});
}


function displayData($http, access_token)
{
$http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {params: {access_token: access_token, fields: "name,gender,location,picture", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
    var name = result.data.name;
    var gender = result.data.gender;
    var picture = result.data.picture;


}, function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error);
});
}
```

Comment: Its NOT working. Login button working fine. but data is not coming.
May be i missed something. 
I changed FB API Key with mine.
Paste this code as it is in my Controller.
Login button still working but User data is not showing. 
Please Explain this Graph thing and how it workis?